# Current and voltage relationship for superconductors

Tags: voltage, current, resistance, kirchhoffs-laws, superconductors

Before superconductors enter our everyday life, we must figure out a way to relate their voltage to current. For example, how would a circuit of two superconducting lamps in series behave? What if they are in parallel? Obviously in their superconducting state we cannot apply Ohm's law to describe them. I guess KCL will still hold but KVL won't hold.

Assume we have two superconducting lamps in series. What will be the overall current? If we add more lamps in series will the current of the circuit be affected?

Comment: There is no V/I relationship. V=0 across the superconductor. KCL and KVL still hold.

Comment: Ok but what if we add 2 superconducting lamps in series?How would that affect the overall current.Would it at all?

Comment: @JonathanS. if you put the superconductor under a ideal voltage source?The KVL obviously wont hold.

Comment: What is a "superconducting lamp"? It drops no voltage, dissipates no power -- real bright idea. :^)

Comment: V=IR would still hold. Super conductors are just where their R=0. If you have a super conductor, that removes votlage drop in that part. You don't have an infinite source in the real wold, so if you made a super conductor loop, you'd have the impedance of the power source as your limiter.

Comment: If you are wanting to look at it purly theortically, then this is a physcis question, not an electronics question.

Comment: If you short an ideal voltage source through an ideal superconductor, the universe will end as infinite current will flow through the loop and thereby create an infinite magnetic field that will tear everything apart, including atoms (and more). Physics will end, time will end, everything will end. The time it takes for the universe to get destroyed depends on the loop's inductance.

Comment: They're not that weird, they're just zero-ohm wires - same as the wires we usually pretend our wires are!

Comment: @TimWilliams a superconducting lamp is a  something that looks like a LED only it is made of superconducting material so we would still have diffusion current and reverse current but 0 ohmic loses

Comment: @appliedSciences KVL will hold but the voltage will be in the non-superconducting part (the wires between the superconductor and the ideal voltage source).

Comment: It should also be pointed out that superconductors stop superconducting when the magnetic field is too strong, and current creates a magnetic field.

Comment: @user253751 I know that I mean when they are in they are in the superconducting state.

Comment: A lamp converts electrical energy into light hence, it cannot be see to be anything like a superconductor (unless it's a lamp that produces zero light output). And, what's the point of that @appliedSciences

Comment: @Puffafish I think the question is fine here, but there is no circuit diagram so it's hard to answer we often talk about ideal circuits. The problem with this question is that even superconductors have resistance there is no zero resistance material

Comment: @Andyaka in LEDs the electrons and holes are driven by diffusion.

Comment: @Andyaka so imagine a lamp made of a pair of materials with 0 electric resistance but due to diffusion and electron-hole generations we have current.

Comment: LEDs @appliedSciences are not superconductors. Superconductors dissipate no power hence, what you describe as a superconducting lamp is either a superconductor that produces zero light output (pointless) or, a non-superconductor that produces light. You can't have both; there is no free-energy.

Comment: @Andyaka im not saying there is free energy but imagine a LED with its crystal lattice having 0 resistance.

Comment: @appliedSciences how will the electrons jump the band gap to produce the photons if there isn't a votlage drop?

Comment: @Puffafish temperature?

Answer (score 2):

> how would a circuit of two superconducting lamps in series behave?

"Superconducting" only applies to *conductors*. It does not apply to *loads*. A lamp is a *load*. It has resistance. Necessarily. Otherwise it could not emit light.

For a load to have continuous power through it, there must be some power source. A power source that gives a nearly fixed voltage is a voltage source. A battery is an example of a voltage source. A real battery will have internal resistance. But, for the purposes of argument, we will assume the existence of an "ideal voltage source", i.e. a voltage source with no internal resistance. Our analysis won't change much by such an assumption.

> I guess KCL will still hold but KVL won't hold.

For a circuit consisting of an ideal voltage source, connected by superconducting wires, to a load, the relationship between the voltage and current will be determined by the nature of the load.

Answer (score 1):

nothing is weird, they are just wires with zero ohms. In all your time studying electronics you've probably been *pretending* that wires are zero ohms, and it doesn't break anything - well now they actually are.

---

If you connect a superconductor to a voltage source all the voltage will be in the part that isn't superconducting (the voltage source).

Superconductors still have inductance, so current cannot go instantly to infinity.

If you somehow make a superconducting voltage source that can deliver infinite current, well, you can't. There are no unstoppable forces or immovable objects. Where does the voltage source get power from, a solar panel, a windmill? Non-superconducting house wiring? You can't get infinite power from a solar panel, nor a windmill, nor from your home's electrical wiring.

If you do put lots and lots of current through a superconductor, it stops superconducting once the magnetic field is too strong. Then you have a normal wire and it melts or whatever.

---

Electrically speaking, the main weird thing about superconductors is that you can have a current that goes forever. This is how MRI magnets work. They charge them up with current one time, then the same current goes around and around for years. Practically speaking it's no different from any other big strong magnet.

This effect also allows for magnetic levitation, but that's not of interest to electronics engineers as it has nothing to do with electronics. You don't have to power up a superconductor to make it levitate things.